# What C type should I use for f64 in my C FFIs?

Tags: rust, ffi

When I return `i32` data from my C FFI functions, I use the datatype `int32_t` and it works like a charm. What is the equivalent of Rust's `f64` datatype in C?

Comment: `double`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types a simple search for C data types would give the answer

Comment: When I tried double clever cargo asked if I did not mean `c_double` from libc. I'm guessing that is it.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Actually, it's probably clever rustc (invoked under the hood by cargo), and yes the suggestion looks correct to me. For a `f32` you would want `c_float`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`libc::c_double`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/type.c_double.html).

Other direct mappings:

```
f32 | c_float   
f64 | c_double  
i8  | int8_t    
i16 | int16_t   
i32 | int32_t   
i64 | int64_t   
u8  | uint8_t
u16 | uint16_t  
u32 | uint32_t  
u64 | uint64_t
```